# React Bootstrap Jumbotrons side by side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
render: function() {
return (
  <div className="loginBox" >
    <h1>Login/SignUp Page</h1>
    <Grid>
      <Jumbotron>
      <h3>Login</h3>
      </Jumbotron>
      <Jumbotron>
      <h3>SignUp</h3>
      </Jumbotron>
      </Grid>
    </div>
);
}
```

Currently, the jumbotrons appear vertically stacked on top of one another. I want the two Jumbotrons to appear side by side, horizontally. How do I accomplish it?

Comment: Use CSS. `display:inline-block`

Comment: As jzm says you have to style it so that it will stack correctly with css. In addition you can use flexbox.

Comment: Use bootstrap grid to align items on your page http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid